# How to enable cookies when POSTING with URLConnection in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cookies, post

I am trying to do a POST towards a site which utilizes secure session with cookies.
Ofcourse this won't work with the code I have posted below. It keeps responding with a non-authorized message.

Is there any way I can use cookies in my code or at least simulate cookie usage?

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://long_and_complicated_url"];
 NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url]; 
 NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Best regards
//Abeansits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK has [cookie support](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-157091) in the form of [NSHTTPCookie](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSHTTPCookie) and [NSHTTPCookieStorage](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSHTTPCookieStorage)

Have you familiarized yourself with these?

Comment: Oh, my bad. =(
Sorry for wasting your time. I was really tiered when I wrote the question.